# Dynamic binding can show protected methods?

Tags: java, oop

parent class

```
package PPRO.Custom.Integration;
public class eInvoice_BSSFormat {
protected void run(String[] param){
}
}
```

other class

```
package PPRO.Custom.Integration;
public class eInvoice_Archon extends eInvoice_BSSFormat{
}
```

another one class

```
package com.birchstreet.smwc.scheduler.jobs;
public class eInvoice_Archon extends PPRO.Custom.Integration.eInvoice_Archon implements Job {
  @Override
  public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
      PPRO.Custom.Integration.eInvoice_Archon arc = new eInvoice_Archon();
      arc.run(args);
    }
```

eclipse  show the problem is

> The method run(String[]) from the type eInvoice_BSSFormat is not
>   visible

we can not changes the existing file only work in new file and we can not use this class object use

when we use like this problem solved

```
eInvoice_Archon arc = new eInvoice_Archon();
```

but we can not use like this only parent reference variable 
how to solve this problem

Comment: Why cannot you do what you suggest? It is the only valid solution.

Comment: problem is that we can not use child class methods only use parent class methods

Answer (score 0):

From [JLS 6.6.2. Details on protected Access](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2)

> A protected member or constructor of an object may be accessed from outside the package in which it is declared only by code that is responsible for the implementation of that object.

Your `protected void run(String[] param)` method is protected so you can only access it within same package or from any class which implements you `eInvoice_BSSFormat`.

Use following:

```
package com.birchstreet.smwc.scheduler.jobs;
public class eInvoice_Archon extends PPRO.Custom.Integration.eInvoice_Archon implements Job {
  @Override
  public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
      //PPRO.Custom.Integration.eInvoice_Archon arc = new eInvoice_Archon();
      this.run(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: in this code  PPRO.Custom.Integration.eInvoice_Archon class extends eInvoice_BSSFormatclass and my class com.birchstreet.smwc.scheduler.jobs.eInvoice_Archon  extends PPRO.Custom.Integration.eInvoice_Archon class. so my class also extends parent's parent class

Comment: Yes , see the code above i have commented out wrong code, you should use this.run(args). You can't call run() from object  `new eInvoice_Archon()`. "Access within  implemented class means call super class method rather creating object.

Answer (score 0):

`run()` method is `protected` so you can only use it in a subclass in a different package

```
  package A;
  class Parent{
     protected int x = 45;
  }

  package B;
  import A.*;
  class Child extends Parent{
    public void access(){
       x= 100; // works
   }
    public void method(){
      Parent p  =new Parent();
       p.x = 150; // error 
    }
 }
```

Comment: my class also a sub class of run method's class

Comment: `PPRO.Custom.Integration.eInvoice_Archon arc = new eInvoice_Archon();
      arc.run(args);` , you can't use `arc` to access `run()` , use `this.run(args)` . protected members can only be accessed through inheritance  from a subclass outside the package.